# Is it possible to add/include javascript file in parent window via cross domain child window iframe?

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

The third party website is calling my iframe. They are cross domain. Now I am trying to push an include script tag in parent window from my iframe, something like following

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    var headTag = window.parent.document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0]; 
    var jqTag = window.parent.document.createElement('script');

    jqTag.type = 'text/javascript';
    jqTag.src = 'http://iframechildwindow.com/js/somejsfile.js';

    headTag.appendChild(jqTag);
</script>
```

But I am getting following error:

> Uncaught SecurityError: Blocked a frame with origin
>   "http://iframechildwindow.com" from accessing a frame with origin
>   "http://websitecallingiframe.com". Protocols, domains, and ports must match.

Actually that parent window was calling one js file from my server by manually calling js file via `<script>` tag, but I want to avoid it and want to make iframe only responsible for all that. Is that possible?

Thanks